# Regex when not finding in all array do something

Tags: regex, perl

I have failed miserably to ask perl to "search in an array for the elements I'm interested at, write their names or write an NA if you don't find them".

For example, suppose that I'm looking for Orc, Troll and Elf in an array

```
    @creatures = qw/Troll Knight Elf Shrubbery Dragon Ni/;
```

How can I check for them and (my big problem) when not finding them writing and NA.
In this example I would look for something like this:

```
    NA  Troll   Elf
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use a hash for quick lookup:

```
my %creatures = map { $_ => 1 } @creatures;

print $creatures{$_} ? $_ : "NA" for qw(Orc Troll Elf);
```

Note that this matches case sensitively, so it will consider "orc" and "Orc" two different things. You can solve this by converting to a specific case beforehand:

```
my %creatures = map { lc($_) => 1 } @creatures;

print $creatures{lc($_)} ? $_ : "NA" for qw(Orc Troll Elf);
```

You can also use `grep`:

```
for my $race (qw(Orc Troll Elf)) {
    if (grep /^$race$/i, @creatures) {
        print $race;
    } else {
        print "NA";
    }
}
```

Note the use of `/i` modifier to make the match case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Smart Match:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my @creatures = qw/Troll Knight Elf Shrubbery Dragon Ni/;
my @searches  = qw/Orc Troll Elf/;

for my $search (@searches) {
    if ($search ~~ @creatures) {
        print $search, ' ';
    } else {
        print "NA ";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With the basic knowledge of perl:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

my @str = qw(Troll Knight Elf Shrubbery Dragon Ni);
my %hash;
my @to_match = qw(Orc Troll Elf);
foreach my $s (@str) {
    $hash{$s} = $s;
}

foreach (@to_match) {
    if (defined $hash{$_}) {
        print "$_ ";
    } else {
        print "NA ";
    }
}
```